# ANGULAR Dynamic Forms - using ASYNC data fails

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic

If you are familiar with this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

While implementing this cookbook, in context of our application, everythings fine when I am getting DATA from a hardcoded ARRAY, but now I am having problems when I am already calling ASYNC methods(hitting the DB and GET). Must be because I am working on observables, I dont know. The array which was supposed to be passed as @Input to  the components that handles dynamic forms seems to be UNDEFINED.It seems that I need to finish the ASYNC call before binding anything to the forms. Here's my code:

**for the SERVICE:**

```
public getTechnicalSettingsList(extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Array<ITechnicalSetting>> {

  return this.getTechnicalSettingsWithHttpInfo(extraHttpRequestParams)

    .map((response: Response) => {
      if (response.status === 204) {
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return response.json();
      }
    });
}
```

**FOR THE COMPONENT:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this._service.getTechnicalSettingsList().subscribe(technicals => {
    this.technicalSettings =  this._service.convertTechnicalSettingsToControls(technicals);

    console.log(this.technicalSettings);
});
```

}

**the HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2> Technical Settings</h2>
 <app-dynamic-form [technicalSettings]="technicalSettings"></app-dynamic-form>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried putting *ngIf="technicalSettings" in <app-dynamic-form>?

Comment: You can use an *ngIf as @JoeWu syas or you can initialize technicalSettings = [] in the class declaration.

Comment: Issue still persists... 
    <div *ngIf="technicalSettings">
      <div *ngFor="let technicalSetting of technicalSettings" class="form-row">
              <app-technical-settings [technicalSetting]="technicalSetting" [form]="form"></app-technical-settings>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: @Joe Wu thanks... I implemented Form Arrays for this one- A different approach... But Joe's answer fixed the error because of undefined objects.. Thanks